# Updated value of Claim is not reflecting in the subsequent requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

In my project, I am using token-based authentication and after a successful login, I store some user-specific values in user's token and to do this I have used Claims.

Below is the code I am using to store claims after login:

```
User user = new UserManager().GetUser(UserName, Password);

var claims = new List<Claim>()
{
   new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.FullName),
   new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email),
   new Claim("IsLocked", Convert.ToString(user.IsLocked))
};

AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(context.UserName);
ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, Startup.OAuthOptions.AuthenticationType);
var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
context.Validated(ticket);
```

As you can see in the above code that I have a claim to store **IsLocked** value of the user. As per the requirement, I need to prevent access of each API action from users whose account is locked. To do so, I have created a custom action filter and inside that, I use the value of **IsLocked** claim and thus prevent actions from being executed if user's claim value says that the user account is locked.

Below is the code of my custom action filter:

```
public class AllowActiveUsersAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public AllowActiveUsersAttribute()
    {

    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var identity = (ClaimsPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal;

        if (Convert.ToBoolean(identity.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "IsLocked").Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault()))
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        }
    }
}
```

And then I use this custom Attribute on all Web API actions, like:

```
[AllowActiveUsers]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAccountDetails()
```

This code works perfectly and I get Unauthorized error when I log in with a locked account and then try to use any API endpoint.

In our system, we have some rules and breaking those rules can lock the users' account. When the account gets locked then the user shouldn't be able to access any API endpoint. So after the successful login (with an account that is not locked), if a user breaks any rule then his/her account should get locked immediately and after that he/she must not be able to use any API endpoints.

To do this, I added code to update the value of **IsLocked** claim and it successfully updates the claim value. But when I try to get the value of **IsLocked** claim in the custom action then I get the same old value instead of the new return value. Below is the code that I am using to update the claim value.

```
// check for the existing claim and remove it
var user = User as ClaimsPrincipal;
var identity = user.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
var claim = (from c in user.Claims where c.Type == "IsLocked" select c).FirstOrDefault();
if (claim != null)
    identity.RemoveClaim(claim);

// add new claim
identity.AddClaim(new Claim("IsLocked", Convert.ToString(true)));
var authenticationManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
authenticationManager.AuthenticationResponseGrant = new AuthenticationResponseGrant(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity), new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = true });
```

Can you please suggest how I can get the new value in the custom attribute so that if a user's account gets locked then from next requests, none of the API requests should be entertained?

Answer (score 0):

That's cause you are still using the old/existing token which still don't have the updated value of `IsLocked` and thus the scenario. To resolve this, either the user has to start afresh by means of generating a new token which would have the updated value. Essentially a new access token has to be generated.

See this issue link for more understanding https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/2783

Comment: Hi Rahul. I know that creating a new access token can resolve this issue, but I am not certain how I can do this. Can you share a code example for the same?

Comment: @MohitThakur I mean the user who is locked has to sign-in again Or if it's Api request then need to generate a new access token by hitting the `/token` endpoint

Comment: I tried to regenerate the token using /token endpoint but even then I can use the API endpoints using the old access token. Any solution for that?